# Background of splash screens aren't visible

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to make splash screen. I have added background image to splash screen's xml. Background image is of only 382 kb in size. but it doesn't show up. But in preview it shows me the image.

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_ground"
    tools:context="com.wisaver.app.updated.activities.SplashSecond">

</RelativeLayout>
```

another splash xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_ground_2"
    tools:context=".updated.activities.SplashActivity">


    <!--<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_splash"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/back_ground_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_splash"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="140dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".updated.activities.SplashSecond"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I'm testing it on Nexus 5. I am developing app with buildToolsVersion 24.0.0. How to make it work? Some help here is appreciated.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SplashSecond.class));
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    th.start();
}
}
```

Here is another one

```
public class SplashSecond extends AppCompatActivity {

//boolean letGo=true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_second);
    Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashSecond.this,ConsumerRetailerActivity.class));
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: it should work.

Comment: Exactly it should work but it doesn't :(

Comment: can you post your SplashActivity Code?

Comment: post everything, including output, and also try it in another lower version devices

Comment: Show `SplashActivity` Code ..... Just a tip , if you are using Android Studio , first clean the project , then try to rebuild it  . Sometimes it doesnt compile fresh changes in the project .

Comment: I have edited the questions. Activity's code has been added

Comment: try to remove tools:context="com.wisaver.app.updated.activities.SplashSecond" in both xmls & restart with invalidate cache

Comment: @MohitTrivedi   what does that line do btw in xml?

Comment: This is most probably the activity the tools UI editor uses to render your layout (it will find the right theme based on the activity)

Comment: same results. I don't see image as background. It shows white background

Comment: have you done restart with invalidate cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124690/discussion-between-mohit-trivedi-and-zeeshan-shabbir).

Comment: can be plz post the device android api version and also the image extension. You should try to load a small image, I recommend.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Thread` code in both activity as follows:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myhandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SplashSecond.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}.start();
```

or You can also try following code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        // Start your app main activity

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SplashSecond.class));

        // close this activity
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to display splash screen.

1.create `activity_splash.xml` in `res/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgSplash"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.add below given code into `SplashActivity.java` class

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private static int SPLASH_DELAY = 2000; //miliseconds
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ImageView imgSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSplash);

        //set your image
        imgSplash.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(this,SPLASH_DELAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

3.change in `AndroidManifest.xml` between `<application>...</application>`

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use low resolution image instead of High resolution because sometimes it will take a high time to load and mean while your screen will disappear due to timer